# Kendo UI filtering a shared datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource

I'm looking at using a single datasource object to populate two separate Kendo UI DropDownList objects. My [datasource](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource) returns JSON in the following format:

```
  [{
    "TableName": "Table_A",
    "FieldCode": "Title_MR",
    "FieldDescription": "MR"
  },    
  {
    "TableName": "Table_A",
    "FieldCode": "Title_MRS",
    "FieldDescription": "MRS"
  },
  {
    "TableName": "Table_B",
    "FieldCode": "Code",
    "FieldDescription": "Z0912"
  }]
```

I know I can filter the datasource itself but I need the filtering to be done on the dropdown objects themselves (using the **TableName** field).

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here the [filter](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-filter) method of the datasource given by the Kendo UI

Comment: The filter method on the datasource isn't usable for my purpose as I need to restrict the data based on the dropdown list.